# Onclick on navigation drawer not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Below is my code. Am having a navigation drawer and on click event not working. On clicking on it am having a fragment to load. But its not working.Am having both sliding menu and Tab layout. Does that make any issues?

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        public static int navItemIndex = 0;
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DrawerLayout drawer;
        private static final String TAG_SOUP = "Soups";
        private static final String TAG_SALADS = "Salads";
        private static final String TAG_MAINCRSE = "Main Course";
        private static final String TAG_BRKDIN = "Tiffin | Breakfast | Dinner";
        private static final String TAG_SNACKS = "Snacks";
        private static final String TAG_BEVERAGES = "Beverages";
        public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SOUP;
        private FloatingActionButton fab;
        private Handler mHandler;
        private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
        private View navHeader;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            mHandler = new Handler();
            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
           // navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


            // initializing navigation menu
            setUpNavigationView();

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                //CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SOUP;
                loadHomeFragment();
            }



            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        private void loadHomeFragment() {
            // selecting appropriate nav menu item
            selectNavMenu();

            // set toolbar title

            // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
            // just close the navigation drawer
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
                drawer.closeDrawers();

                // show or hide the fab button
                toggleFab();
                return;
            }

            Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // update the main content by replacing fragments
                    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            };

            // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
            if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
            }
        }


        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new SoupFragment(), TAG_SOUP);
            adapter.addFragment(new SaladFragment(), TAG_SALADS);
            adapter.addFragment(new MainCoursesFragment(), TAG_MAINCRSE);
            adapter.addFragment(new TifBrkDinFragment(), TAG_BRKDIN);
            adapter.addFragment(new SnacksFragment(), TAG_SNACKS);
            adapter.addFragment(new BeveragesFragments(), TAG_BEVERAGES);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
                // checking if user is on other navigation menu
                // rather than home
                if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SOUP;
                    loadHomeFragment();
                    return;
                }
            }
                super.onBackPressed();

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
            switch (navItemIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // soup
                    SoupFragment soupFragment = new SoupFragment();
                    return soupFragment;
                case 1:
                    // salads
                    SaladFragment saladFragment = new SaladFragment();
                    return saladFragment;
                case 2:
                    // Main courses
                    MainCoursesFragment mainCoursesFragment = new MainCoursesFragment();
                    return mainCoursesFragment;
                case 3:
                    // Breakfast | Tiffin | Dinner
                    TifBrkDinFragment tifBrkDinFragment = new TifBrkDinFragment();
                    return tifBrkDinFragment;

                case 4:
                    // Snacks
                    SnacksFragment snacksFragment = new SnacksFragment();
                    return snacksFragment;

                case 5:
                    // Beverages
                    BeveragesFragments beveragesFragments = new BeveragesFragments();
                    return beveragesFragments;
                default:
                    return new SaladFragment();
            }
        }

        private void selectNavMenu() {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
        }

        private void setUpNavigationView() {
            //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                        case R.id.nav_soup:
                            navItemIndex = 0;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SOUP;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_salads:
                            navItemIndex = 1;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SALADS;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_main_course:
                            navItemIndex = 2;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MAINCRSE;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_brktifdin:
                            navItemIndex = 3;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_BRKDIN;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_snacks:
                            navItemIndex = 4;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SNACKS;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_beverages:
                            // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                          //  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                           // drawer.closeDrawers();
                            navItemIndex = 5;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_BEVERAGES;
                            break;
                        default:
                            navItemIndex = 0;
                    }

                    //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                    if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);

                    loadHomeFragment();

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        // show or hide the fab
        private void toggleFab() {
            if (navItemIndex == 0)
                fab.show();
            else
                fab.hide();
        }
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_soup:
                fragment = new SoupFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_salads:
                fragment = new SaladFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_main_course:
                fragment = new MainCoursesFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_brktifdin:
                fragment = new TifBrkDinFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_snacks:
                fragment = new SnacksFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_beverages:
                fragment = new BeveragesFragments();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null)  {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           //
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
    }
```

Comment: u need to click navigation item move to that specific tabhost fragment right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I need to move to that specific tabhost.

Comment: Where is your onClickListener ? Are you calling some function in onClick of xml file ?

Comment: I have edited my code. Please check it.

Comment: The probelem is I have  "onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)" method. While debugging i have break point in this method. when I click on the navigation drawer, the compiler doesn't hit there.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code ...!**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package co.in.example.app.tab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;
protected TabFragment tabFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    tabFragment = new TabFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, tabFragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        tabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        tabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        tabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**TabFragment.java**

```
package co.in.example.app.tab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener,
    OnTabChangeListener {
public TabHost tabHost;
private int currentTab = 0;
public ViewPager viewPager;
protected TabPagerAdapter pageAdapter;
private List<Fragment> fragments;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabhost, null);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(new FragmentImport());
    fragments.add(new FragmentGallery());
    fragments.add(new FragmentSlideShow());
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    pageAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),
            fragments, getArguments());
    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    setupTabs();
}


private void setupTabs() {
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.addTab(newTab(R.string.imports));
    tabHost.addTab(newTab(R.string.gallery));
    tabHost.addTab(newTab(R.string.slideshow));

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
        changeTextColor(i);
    }
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
}

private TabSpec newTab(int tabValue) {
    TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), tabValue));
    //tabSpec.setIndicator(tabValue, null);
    tabSpec.setContent(new Dummy(getActivity()));
    return tabSpec;
}

private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(title);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentTab);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        changeTextColor(i);
    }
}

private void changeTextColor(int i) {
    if (currentTab == i) {
        final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_un_select));
    }
}


public class Dummy implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    private Context context;

    public Dummy(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        return new View(context);
    }
}
}
```

**TabPagerAdapter.java**

```
package co.in.example.app.tab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import java.util.List;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Bundle args;
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments,
                       Bundle args) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.args = args;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
}
```

// Create a fragments as you needs
**FragmentGallery.java**

```
package co.in.example.app.tab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentGallery extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_gallery, container, false);
}
}
```

slide menu item

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/imports" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/slideshow" />
</group>

</menu>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="co.in.example.app.tab.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**tabhost.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_bg"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="none"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

// Create fragment xml file
**fragment_fragment_import.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="co.in.example.app.tab.FragmentImport">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Import" />

</FrameLayout>
```